# Accessing a computer by the public IP

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ip, nat

A theoretic question :

If i have a cloud account in amazon EC2, (or at all...)
and i access an instance from another instance by its public IP and not its Private IP,
Will it make a difference ? will the routers/switches know that they are in the same network or will the information go outside and inside again ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you connect via public DNS. EC2 automatically resolves it to an internal IP within ec2 and external IP outside of ec2. The form of the public DNS follows a simple pattern that incorporates the public IP.

Comment: and if i connect via public ip ? not the dns... (instead of ec2-50-20-150-30.compute-1.amazonaws.com => 50.20.150.30)

Comment: If you connect via public IP, it may get routed to the edge routers before getting routed back in. You may be charged for traffic in this case.